# Send HTTP 418 I'm a teapot

Tags: php, http

I have a web-server and I would like to have the HTTP status code 418 'I'm a teapot' under some conditions, I am sure I would use an if statement, I just can't seem to get it to trip, any help?

Comment: What do you mean "Under some conditions?"

Comment: Like the first time a user visits on the first of April.

Comment: Start here, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: I know how to use if, while, d while, ect, I just need to get the code to return...

Comment: Use the `header()` function, beware of [error cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php), and note that you can't usually show a page along (built-in browser replacements).

Comment: I use header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found") to try a common code, but it does nothing, first line after <?php

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a teapot");
?>
<html>
<h1>418 I'm a teapot</h1><br>
<p>The HTCPCP Server is a teapot. The responding entity MAY be short and stout.</p>
</html>
```

Will result in:

## 418 I'm a teapot

The HTCPCP Server is a teapot. The responding entity MAY be short and stout.